# Очередь в сетевом интерфейсе

Tags: сеть, unix

У меня есть MPP база данных, которая сильно зависит от сети. Иногда передача данных не превышает 150-250 Мбит, а получения - 100-150 Мбит. При нормальной работе данные в несколько раз больше. Хочу убедиться, что это проблема сети. По-идее сетевая очередь должна быть забита. Подскажите, как в консоле получить текущий размер буфера или очереди в сетевом интерфейсе? Буфер и очередь не одно и то же?

Comment: Не уверен, что понял  ваше описание ситуации, а как можно  посмотреть размеры написано, например,  [тут](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning/) (нагуглено по `linux interface buffer size`)